# Select from two tables and create object with data

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to fetch data from two MySQL tables and push each into array. 
I have to tables item and user with the same column - item_id. Now im requesting the data from them with

`var query = "SELECT * FROM items, users WHERE items.item_id=?";
 query = connection.format(query,req.params.item_id);`

After this, im getting a wall of data. Like this:

```
{
 { user_id: 13213,
   user_name: 'John',
   item_id: 1337,
   item_name: Leet stuff,
   item_price: 13,37
 }, 
 { user_id: 12345,
   user_name: 'Mike',
   item_id: 1337,
   item_name: Leet stuff,
   item_price: 13,37
 }
```

But what I actualy need is this:

```
{
 users: [
  { user_id: 13213,
    user_name: 'John'
  },
  { user_id: 12345,
    user_name: 'Mike'
  }
 ],
  item_id: 1337,
  item_name: Leet stuff,
  item_price: 13,37
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in a single query. However, you can use two different queries and combine the output, e.g.:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name 
FROM users u JOIN ITEMS i ON j.user_id = i.user_id
WHERE i.item_id = ?;
```

This will give you the list of users. You can then use the below query to get the item details:

```
SELECT item_id, item_name, item_price
FROM items 
WHERE item_id = ?
```

You can then construct the required structure in your application.